# Google script - How to have a sheet used by another person and here a function that will modify data in a protected area by me

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a question on how a function can still interact on a protected cell on which a user has no direct access.

let's imagine a very simple sheet in which I just want that anyone (so someone else than me) working on it will **though a function** update columns n°1 and n°2 on the row he is and this function put on both the current date .
.... but ... In the same time I protected the column n°1 so that it is only editable by me.
Rq : for the test column n°2 is not protected

### Observations :

- If there is no protection ... the function update correctly the col n°1 n°2 and put the date in both cell
- As soon as there is the protection , the function runs but exit at the moment it try to update the column n°1, as consequence it even do not update column n°2

### My dreams :

As I'm the owner of the sheet as well as the code, I would be super interested to find a way so that 
1) my code is protected and hence cannot be modified by anybody 
2) still my code is executed and modify what I want even if used by someone on a protected cell

Somehow this is just the natural approach of the object model and the modification of private data through a public function.

The example with date is basic and stupid but it will allow to put more complex logic with some data that cannot be modified by anyone (like a data hash or a last updating date for exemple)

PLEASE HELP !!!!!!

MERCI

To test this :

Just open the script editor in an, empty sheet and put this code

```
function onEdit (e)
{
   var CurRow = e.range.getRow();
   e.getActiveSheet().getRange(CurRow, 1,).setValue(new Date());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Why does protection exist in sheets?**

Answer: to prevent your *trusted* users from *accidentally* making edits.

**Point #1** Nothing is *really* protected if someone has edit access to your sheet.

**Point #2** Just make those specific cells unprotected, if you let them edit your cells with a function then they are not protected anymore because they can go in the GAS(Google App Script) editor and make it whatever they want...

**Summary:** If you give someone edit access to your sheet nothing is really protected, if you can't trust your editors you are going to need to have them edit this sheet from outside of google sheets.

**Bonus:**
`onEdit` is unreliable and does not always execute.